# Creating universal app trying to implemenet shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, orientation

I created a single view universal app, and made sure that the method shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation has been implemented in my ViewController.m, well when I launch the simulator and rotate the device it doesnt do anything when I rotate. I have verified that in my plist all 4 orientations are added, all four of the buttons are selected. I havent added any other controllers to the view and it doesnt work what am I missing? It rotates just fine in when running the iPhone version. I am using storyboards here, so I have an iPhone and iPad storyboard. I even added a breakpoint to that method and it is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPad and iPhone use different setting. Are you sure you selected all four orientations for iPad?

Please double check "iPad Deployment Info" in your targets setting - Summary tab.

Comment: Yes, I already checked that too. I am really baffled on why it wont work.